# How to prove two differential structures are distinct

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

When I read the book An Introduction to Manifolds written by Loring W. Tu, chapter 6, there is a problem to show two differential structures are distinct. I wanna ask that will proving two charts' coordinate maps are not compatible make sense? And how can one to know two differential structures are distinct?

Comment: Assuming we are speaking of one space $M$, show that there is no diffeomorphism $f: (M, A_1) \rightarrow (M, A_2)$, where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are different smooth structures.

Comment: @gian so I just have to show $fg^{-1}$ is not smooth?

Comment: The map $f$ could fail to be a diffeomorphism at different levels. It might not be bijective, it might not be continuous, and it might not be smooth. Assuming it is these things, then you'd need to show that for any map $g$ in the reverse direction, $fg$ is not smooth, which would then imply $f$ has no smooth inverse.

Comment: @gian thanks a lot !